# Reducing agent in preparation of CpRuCl(PPh3)2

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

Synthesis of cyclopentadienyl-bis-triphenylphosphine-ruthenium chloride $\ce{RuCl(PPh3)2(\eta^5-C5H5)})$:

Dissolved $\ce{PPh3}$, $\ce{RuCl3.3H2O}$ and cyclopentadiene in ethanol and heated under reflux to prepare it.

What is the reducing agent and what is the product formed on oxidation of this reducing agent?

The ruthenium is being reduced but i don't know what is being oxidised.

Answer (score 1):

You'd think it's the ethanol solvent that acts as the reducing agent here, and the byproduct is acetaldehyde.

Comment: Could it be possible that triphenylphosphine is the reducing agent here, going to triphenylphosphine oxide?

Comment: @jerepierre I believe that is correct.

Comment: @jerepierre Couldn't it also be cyclopentadiene, in excess, dimerising? The [described synthesis is behind a paywall](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780470132524.ch17/summary) for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the synthesis of [dichlorotris(triphenylphosphine)ruthenium(II)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichlorotris(triphenylphosphine)ruthenium(II)), a similar complex, $\ce{PPh3}$ is the reducing agent which is oxidized to triphenylphosphine oxide, $\ce{Ph3PO}$ (references: [1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016%2F0022-1902%2866%2980191-4), [2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002%2F9780470132432.ch40)). The reaction is driven by the strength of the $\ce{P=O}$ double bond.

$$\ce{2 RuCl3 \cdot 3H2O + 7 PPh3 ~->~ 2 RuCl2(PPh3)3 + 2 HCl + 5 H2O + OPPh3}$$